# How to run phpunit testcases for impacted codes changes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have more than 1000s of  unit tests for my application and it takes hour to run the test and get the results. how do we configure to run phpunit to run all only those testcases that has dependency / impact of the current change.

E.g if I change a method in the class **A** and this method is called in one of the method of Class **B**. I have Unit tests written for class **A, B  & C**. I want to execute only testcases for class A's method that has been changed and class's B method that has called it.

Edit: I'm using Jenkins to automatically test the code ,how will my phpunit know what has been changed so it will trigger the phpunit for impacted code change.

Comment: You can use annotations to create test groups: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/annotations.html#group

Comment: Are you talking unit tests or integration tests? Unit tests, even when you have thousands, shouldn't really take an hour. Did you give your jenkins server a really bad cpu? If they are integration tests, how would you expect phpunit to know which tests it should rerun? It can't determine the new scope before running them all. Which kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @DirkScholten , I'm using laravel framework that has included phpunit to test features. My questions is based on that , if I'm not using right testing framework , please suggest for the same